# Mulesoft using PostgresSQL

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Need small help

I want to execute Select * from emp in Mule(transform message) using PostgresSQL  but  it is not taking *  instead it is taking only column names like empno,ename,firname etc..  but I want to use  *  as my table is having almost 100 plus columns.

Can anyone suggest how to handle ?

Comment: Please edit your comment and add the operation or operations in the flow that you are trying to execute, as text XML. Don't use screenshots. What is the result if you try using *? is there an error, an unexpected result, what? show that too.

Comment: Note that using `select *` is usually considered a bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.